# (thread_id_key != 0x7777), function find_thread_id_key, file ../src/coroutine.cc, line 134

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-component

i'm working on a vue program, i tried `npm run serve` then i got this:

```sh
66% building 670/715 modules 45 active /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/echarts/lib/chart/graph.js## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`/Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-93/fibers.node` is missing.

Try running this to fix the issue: /usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0/bin/node /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/fibers/build
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-93/fibers'
Require stack:
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/getSassOptions.js
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:940:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:773:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:14:39)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at getSassOptions (/Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/getSassOptions.js:49:25)
    at Object.loader (/Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:48:51)
    at LOADER_EXECUTION (/Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:119:14)
    at runSyncOrAsync (/Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:120:4)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
69% building 1077/1094 modules 17 active /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/echarts/lib/coord/radar/IndicatorAxis.js## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`/Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-93/fibers.node` is missing.

Try running this to fix the issue: /usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0/bin/node /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/fibers/build
```

then i run`node /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/fibers/build`to compile `fiber`. Afer build i run `npm run serve` again. then error shows as below:

```sh
> omega-fe@1.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
42% building 268/307 modules 39 active /Users/bytedance/go/src/code.byted.org/ad/omega_fe/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.array.splice.jsAssertion failed: (thread_id_key != 0x7777), function find_thread_id_key, file ../src/coroutine.cc, line 134.
Abort trap: 6
```

i have tried reinstall node&&vue. My system is MacOs 11.2.3, node version:16.0.0, npm version: 7.11.0

Any suggesion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 94):

This error is due to the deprecation of node-fibers for node >=16.x released on April 20, 2021.

On the [fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) project README:

> Update [April 13th, 2021] -- Fibers is not compatible with nodejs v16.0.0 or later. Unfortunately, v8 commit dacc2fee0f is a breaking change and workarounds are non-trivial.

Downgrading node to a lower version (15.14.0) with [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) did the trick on my end

Edit: More detailed answer

Comment: this fixed my build issue - thanks! I was using FROM node:alpine in my docker file and needed to specify node:15-apline to switch back to node v15. I guess I need to start specifying specific image versions if I want a reliable build process.

Comment: I faced this error while working on the `webdriverio` project. I also learnt about `nvm` and did not really have any idea about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

I have an exact problem with nuxt project.
My solution is to uninstall from package.json `fiber`

Comment: but how? i had run  `npm uninstall fiber` before……

Comment: @Azure: remove `fiber` from package.json then do `rm -rf node-modules package-lock.json && npm i`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue - the root cause is having the "fibers" module in the project when using node.js v16 or up. Sass-loader relied on fibers until very recent versions, so given your above stacktrace, that's likely the culprit here:

1. Remove fibers:

   ```
   npm uninstall --save-dev fibers
   ```
2. "Hard" update sass-loader:

   ```
   npm uninstall --save-dev sass-loader
   npm install --save-dev sass-loader
   ```
3. Wipe & reinstall the node_modules folder:

   ```
    rm -rf ./node_modules
    npm install
   ```
4. Rerun Webpack

If it's still not working after that, try checking package-lock.json for node-fibers, and upgrading any libraries that still depend on it.

Answer (score 6):

I also got this error with Nuxt.js and Node.js v16.7.
Nothing worked but downgrading to Node.js v14 or v15.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error while upgrading to Node 16.x. @wdio/sync package was causing this error as it has a dependency on @types/fibers. Luckily we were not using the async and await . so uninstalling the @wdio/sync package resolved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem because I had updated my NodeJS from v12 to v18. To fix this I had to delete `node_modules` folder from my project and run `npm install`.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute:

```
npm uninstall fibers && rm package-lock.json && rm -R node_modules && npm install
```