# Command failed with exit code 134: npm run generate

Tags: node.js, vue.js, continuous-integration, nuxt.js, netlify

I'm trying to deploy my nuxt js project to netlify. The installation part works fine, But it returns an error in the build process.

I tried to search google but I can't find any solution to this problem.

I also tried this command `CI= npm run generate`

```
3:16:42 PM: $ npm run generate
3:16:43 PM: > portfolio@1.0.0 generate
3:16:43 PM: > nuxt generate
3:16:50 PM: node: ../src/coroutine.cc:134: void* find_thread_id_key(void*): Assertion `thread_id_key != 0x7777' failed.
Aborted
3:16:50 PM: ​
3:16:50 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:16:50 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
3:16:50 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:16:50 PM: ​
3:16:50 PM:   Error message
3:16:50 PM:   Command failed with exit code 134: npm run generate
3:16:50 PM: ​
3:16:50 PM:   Error location
3:16:50 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
3:16:50 PM:   npm run generate
3:16:50 PM: ​
3:16:50 PM:   Resolved config
3:16:50 PM:   build:
3:16:50 PM:     command: npm run generate
3:16:50 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
3:16:50 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/dist
3:16:50 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
3:16:50 PM: Caching artifacts
3:16:50 PM: Started saving node modules
3:16:50 PM: Finished saving node modules
3:16:50 PM: Started saving build plugins
3:16:50 PM: Finished saving build plugins
3:16:50 PM: Started saving pip cache
3:16:50 PM: Finished saving pip cache
3:16:50 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
3:16:50 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
3:16:50 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
3:16:50 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
3:16:50 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
3:16:50 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
3:16:50 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
3:16:50 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
3:16:50 PM: Started saving go dependencies
3:16:50 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
3:16:52 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
3:16:52 PM: Creating deploy upload records
3:16:52 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
3:16:52 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
3:16:52 PM: Finished processing build request in 1m34.230804646s
```

Here is the Nuxt Config -
My target is to build a static site. You may guess this is my portfolio site. I'm working on my portfolio to get a better job.

`nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'Hasibur',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '@/assets/scss/main.scss'
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/components.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/fontawesome.js', mode: 'client' },
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {},

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work locally? Also, can you please share your `nuxt.config.js` file? Also, do you know what is `coroutine.cc`?

Comment: Yes, It works locally very well.  And I don't know this file ```coroutine.cc``` .

Comment: What if you generate your project and then, upload your `/dist` directory on app.netlify.com/drop?

Comment: The problem was ```fibers````. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had the same problem and solved it thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67330252/thread-id-key-0x7777-function-find-thread-id-key-file-src-coroutine-cc). The problem seems to be [fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers).

The steps I took to fix it:

1. uninstall fibers: `npm uninstall fibers`
2. delete `package-lock.json` & `node_modules/`
3. install packages again: `npm install`

Simply removing fibers from `package.json` isn't enough as Netlify seems to still find the package in `package-lock.json`.

Comment: But I have to use fibers because I'm using ```sass``` and ```sass-loader```. Nuxt required 
to use ```fibers``` when you need ```sass```

Comment: Nuxt doesn't require it, they just recommended it since it improved build time. When you look in the docs now, they actually [don't mention it anymore](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/configuration#pre-processors).